# Как отключить на мобильной версии сайта скрипты?

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте подскажите как отключить на мобильной версии сайта ненужные скрипты ?за ранние спасибо.

Comment: простите, за ранние что спасибо?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, за ранние ответы

Comment: @vp_arth чёрт побери, я точно такой же коммент хотел написать в ответ. Сидел тупил сейчас 2 секунды, смотря, думая, на свой коммент :D

Comment: заранее спасибо, имелось ввиду!

Answer (score 1):

Например, нужные скрипты, помещаем в проверку:

```
if (window.innerWidth < 1024) {
  //помещаем сюда скрипты для десктоп версии
} else { 
  //сюда скрипты для мобильной версии
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть js библиотеки, которые позволяют отличать десктоп от мобилок, например [current-device.js](https://github.com/matthewhudson/current-device). Вот такой код решает все проблемы:

```
if(device.mobile()) {
    // код для мобилок
} else {
    // код для десктопа
}
```